# Cannot implicitly convert type issues in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am fairly new to MVC.

So I have a model defined as

```
[Table("Roles")]
public class RolesModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Role ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Role Name")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

And in the controller, I want to create a getall class doing like:

```
        public List<RolesController> GetAll()
    {
        return db.RolesModels.ToList();
    }
```

However, It keeps giving me the error for Cannot implicitly convert type issues

Did I miss anything here please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should indicate which types it is trying to convert that it can't.  In GetALL() the return is returning a list of RolesModels but the method signature indicates it should return a list of RolesControllers.  It does not know how to convert between the two.  You have to provide that but you might just have an incorrect signature.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks, but what do you mean by signature and how do I go change that please. Thank you

Comment: public List<RolesController> GetAll() is the signature of the GetAll method.  It indicates what parameters (none in this case) and what the return value should be which is List<RolesController> in this case.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask what do you suggest me to change to. I had this getall signature for another model and controller and it worked fine.